# SMS_SEND permission causes compile error and alert antivirus

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Basically, I searched through all the internet and found big, fat zero about that.

My app is using sms sending service and I need SMS_SEND permission. When I add it and run - Eclipse says that I have errors in my code AND antivirus alert that they blocked Android.Trojan.SMS_SEND.NR. I don't care about the latter - because it doesn't show up without SMS_SEND permission.

All I found is in Lint Error Checking:
"Looks for permissions that are only granted to system apps

Permissions with the protection level signature or signatureOrSystem are only granted to system apps. If an app is a regular non-system app, it will never be able to use these permissions."

BUT what matters the most - other app tha use that permission is fine. So what could happened? I need that service to be in that app.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mypackage.etc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ on Linux, my app uses SMS_SEND permission and I've never had any problems. I'd try to disable Anti-Virus.

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Android AV Software (F-Secure?) is blocking the code probably based on heuristics or signature. As *most if not all* Android AV Software is worthless I'd remove that first. Assuming you are not using a rooted device it must simply be picking this up from a manifest scan or some use of the Package Manager.

The "signature or signatureOrSystem" is not applicable to the SEND_SMS permission and whilst you may find a use for using the signature permission cross (identically signed) applications, it is unlikely you are using this.

Please show us your manifest.

Comment: Man, You're good - yes, it's F-Secure (on computer, not smartphone since app never reach it). Gotta change that, but I'm curious why it happened now and not once before? And why eclipse is showing this error as well (it's not only antivir that's complaining).

Comment: Most AV Software if not all within Android is sandboxed within a Dalvik VM instance and therefore if your device is not rooted it has only limited information on your environment. You should show us your Manifest file. As the AV Software is picking this up simply disable it selectively if you can.

Comment: Manifest looks fine. What compile time errors are you getting from eclipse?

Comment: Oh, wait - after disabling antivir I can now run my app! Seems like F-Secure was a troublemaker. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62548/discussion-between-littlescala-and-jean-darme).